# number of paths on n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

If we have a vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ vertices how many paths can we have on this vertex set?

My guess is $n!$ since to form a path we choose a vertex out of those, and then its neighbors one by one. Is this correct?

Update: If the ordering matters then it is $n!$. Otherwise, we divide this by n.

Comment: If $n=3$, are $123$ and $231$ the same or different paths?

Comment: @copper.hat different I think, the task does not say anything about that

Comment: Then it is the same as the number of permutations of $n$ objects (with an implicit return to the start).

Comment: @copper.hat so $n!$ satisfies it. and what if they are not different?

Comment: For a given permutation, how many starting points are there on the same path?

Comment: Can they make a loop?

Comment: @copper.hat well, $n$ since we have $n$ vertices?

Comment: @shrinitsingh Paths do not have loops?

Comment: Ooops, ignore my comment about return to start. Lack of caffeine (or brain cells).

Comment: @mandella: Yes, so if the starting point does not matter then there are $(n-1)!$ such objects. If it matters then it is $n!$.

Comment: thanks a ton @copper.hat

Comment: @copper.hat do you know about the number of double stars on this vertex set? My guess is that we have to pick 2 vertices to be the center but I am not sure about the total number.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by double stars.

Comment: @copper.hat check this: http://www.tankonyvtar.hu/en/tartalom/tamop412A/2011-0013_galambos_introduction_to_graph/321_some_special_trees.html

Comment: @mandella Do the paths in question have to have length exactly n? Because of not, then n! is not right, you can have many more of smaller length.

Comment: No the path have length n-1, the number of vertices is n. So in fact I think that there are $n!/2$ trees like this. @copper.hat